# how can i retrieve static value as column in sequelize findAll

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In mysql query if I want to retrieve static value as column in select query I would normally use following statement:

```
SELECT 
  ...,
  "static value" as static_value
FROM table_name;
```

How can I accomplish such queries in sequelize findAll?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sequelize.literal()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal)

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: ['foo', 'bar', [sequelize.literal('static value'), 'static_value']]
});
```

Which is the equivalent of

```
SELECT foo, bar, 'static value' AS static_value FROM ...
```

Comment: Please use the static value within the quote else sequelize will assume it as a column name.
like this 
[sequelize.literal('"static value"'), 'static_value']